# VC++ experimental modules does not work

Tags: c++, visual-studio, module, visual-studio-2017, c++-experimental

I am trying the experimental implementation for modules in Visual Studio 2017, version 15.4.4. I followed the instructions described here https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2017/05/05/cpp-modules-in-visual-studio-2017/. I was able to make this run pretty quickly in a console application.

```
import std.core;
int main()
{
   std::cout << "Hello modules!" << std::endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Importing and using the available standard modules is not a problem (as far as I tried to far).

However, when I define my own module, nothing works. I added a file *system.ixx* (item type C/C++ compiler), with the following content:

```
import std.core;
export import system.io;

export struct console
{
   void write(std::string_view text) { std::cout << text; }
   void write_line(std::string_view text) { std::cout << text << std::endl; }   
};
```

when I add `import system.io` to *main.cpp*

```
import std.core;
import system.io;

int main()
{
   std::cout << "Hello modules!" << std::endl;
   return 0;
}
```

I get the following errors:

```
1>system.ixx
1>system.ixx(2): error C2230: could not find module 'system.io'
1>main.cpp
1>main.cpp(2): error C2230: could not find module 'system.io'
```

I also added `/module:reference system.io.idf`  to the compiler options, but there is no *system.io.idf* file generated out of *system.ixx*.

I know this is experimental and has lots of issues, but I was wondering was should I do to make this simple thing work.

Comment: "If you want to use modules for header other than the standard library headers, the standard library modules are produced using the /module:export switch described in the initial C++ modules blog post"

Comment: I added a pre-built step with the following command `cl.exe /MDd /experimental:module /module:name system.io /module:export system.ixx /module:stdIfcDir "$(VCToolsInstallDir_150)ifc\$(PlatformTarget)"`. What I get now is an error on the export declaration for the module: `system.ixx(2): error C2263: 'system.io': you cannot import a module into itself`.

Answer (score 0):

In `system.ixx`, try changing `export import system.io` to `export module system.io`. You also want to make sure that the `export module ...` declaration appears at the top of the file. So `system.ixx` becomes:

```cpp
export module system.io;
import std.core;

export struct console
{
   void write(std::string_view text) { std::cout << text; }
   void write_line(std::string_view text) { std::cout << text << std::endl; }   
};
```